# How can I know what static configuration file does my salt-call is using?

Tags: salt-stack

Is there a command that I can use to know what static configuration file does my salt-call is using?

Answer (score 0):

Probably enabling the `LOG_LEVEL` could help, for example within the minion you could use:

```
salt-call -l trace state.highstate
```

or to be more verbose:

```
salt-call -l debug state.highstate
```

You also have:

```
salt-call state.show_highstate
```

or

```
salt-call state.show_lowstate
```

Check the [COMPILER BASICS](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/compiler_ordering.html#compiler-basics) docs to get more info about it